# WFP filter: Raw TCP packets dropped when sent via FwpsInjectNetworkSendAsync

Tags: networking, tcp, driver, wfp

I registered a kernel WFP filter at FWPM_LAYER_OUTBOUND_IPPACKET_V4, where I copy each IPv4 NET_BUFFER_LIST to a buffer and reinject it unmodified from a worker thread. I'm using FWPM_SUBLAYER_UNIVERSAL as a sublayer. Basically:

```
mdl = IoAllocateMdl(buffer, ...)
MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool(mdl);
FwpsAllocateNetBufferAndNetBufferList0(..., mdl, ..., &nbl)
FwpsInjectNetworkSendAsync0(..., nbl, ...)
```

which returns 0, as well as NET_BUFFER_LIST_STATUS() from the sendComplete callback.

This works for UDP and ICMP (I get replies back), but not for TCP packets. I can see the SYN going out in NetMon from a virtual machine where I'm testing, but NetMon doesn't see the packet coming outside (in the host machine). And no reply from the remote host of course.

I tried updating the IP checksum (which I get as 0 in the classifyFn) and it doesn't change anything. The TCP checksum is already correct when my classifyFn receives it (as far as NetMon can tell). I looked at the original nbl, my flat buffer and the newly created nbl in WinDBG, and they all contain the IP packet (starting with 0x45, etc).

Do I have to create a new sublayer for the filter ? Are the packets dropped because I'm calling sendAsync from a worker thread associated with the system process ?

Answer (score 1):

Replying to my own question: apparently updating all the checksums (including tcp/udp) before reinjecting the packet solves the issue.